# How Sub classing with extends for React or Javascript work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understand sub classing with extends for example

```
class Car extends Vehicle {}
class Dog extends Animal {}
```

But with React, you may see

```
class HelloMessage extends React.Component {}
```

What does the dot between React and Component mean? How does it work in React and in vanilla Javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes do not have to be standalone variable names - they may be properties of objects as well. So `extends React.Component`, absent any other context of what React is, just means that `React` is an object with has a `Component` property which is a class.

For an example of how to emulate this in vanilla JS:

```js
const obj = {
  Foo: class Foo {
    doThing() {
      console.log('doing thing');
    }
  }
};

class MySubClass extends obj.Foo {
  subMethod() {
    console.log('submethod');
  }
}

const s = new MySubClass();
s.doThing();
s.subMethod();
```

React is doing the same sort of thing. It's just a way to organize data as properties of objects.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your explanation!